# Does Raney nickel deprotect acetals?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reference-request, organocatalysis

I know that Raney nickel can deprotect thioacetals. Can it deprotect acetals as well?

I found this image which shows that it deprotects and removes many protecting groups. But there was no reference to deprotection of acetals.

[image: Reaction scheme]

Comment: In my experience it does not,

Comment: Raney Ni cleaves C-S bonds.